# Inverting UTF16 to UTF8 conversion for astral characters

Tags: node.js, encoding, utf-8, utf-16, utf

My question is simple. Start with a character that is not in the basic multilingual plane, say `var original = ""` or equivalently

```
var original=`\u{1f3ae}`
```

Javascript stores this string in memory via UTF-16 encoding. Unfortunately, you give the string to some database/application (specifics irrelevant) and it mis-interprets the UTF-16 bytes as UTF-8 bytes, and when you read out the string from the database/application what it actually gives you is precisely

```
var switchedEncoding = Buffer.from(original, 'utf16le').toString('utf8')
```

If you log `switchedEncoding` in this case you get `<خ�`. Not good. Okay, so you try to switch it back:

```
var switchedBack = Buffer.from(switchedEncoding,'utf8').toString('utf16le')
```

If you log `switchedBack` in this case you get `�붿` not . Bummer.

On the otherhand if your original string is in the BMP, `switchedBack` recovers the original just fine. My question is whether or not information is irreversibly lost by the incorrect decoding done by the application/database? If not, I would like a clever function that can invert it even for characters in the astral planes.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was as follows. I could get the database (a leveldb) to read things out into a buffer, and then I used the following approach using the `iconv` package in node:

```
const Iconv = require("iconv").Iconv;
let iconv = new Iconv("UTF-8","UTF-16LE");
let iconv2 = new Iconv("UTF-16LE","UTF-8");
let original = "\u{1f3ae}"
let switched = iconv.convert(original)
let switchedBack = iconv2.convert(switched)
console.log(original)
console.log(switched.toString())
console.log(switchedBack.toString())


// So it's the switched.toString() which is not recoverable; 
// switched itself (a Buffer) is;
```

Good to know that `Buffer.toString('someEncoding')` is not always invertible if the encoding of the bytes in the buffer isn't `someEncoding`.